# Running a for loop inside html file for specific time in django

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models, django-templates

I want a for loop to run 2/3 times for this specific model. Lets assume I have 10 data, I want the first 3 one to be shown inside html file through a for loop. Can anyone help me with this one?

This is the models.py

```
class CompanyInformation(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
details = models.TextField(max_length=50)
website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
social_fb = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
social_ig = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py file

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
# Create your views here.

def aboutpage(request):
    aboutinfo = CompanyInformation.objects.all()[0]
    context={
        'aboutinfo' : aboutinfo,
    }
    return render(request, 'aboutpage.html', context)
```

inside the html file

```
{% block body_block %}


<p class="redtext">{{ aboutinfo.name }}</p>
<p class="redtext">{{ aboutinfo.details }}</p>
<p class="redtext">{{ aboutinfo.website }}</p>


{% endblock body_block %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just sending single object through context try sending 3 of them:

```
company_info_objs = CompanyInformation.objects.all()[:3]
context={
        'company_info_objs' : company_info_objs,
    }
```

Then you can loop through them inside the templates as follows:

```
{% for company_info in company_info_objs %}
    <p class="redtext">{{ company_info.name }}</p>
    <p class="redtext">{{ company_info.details }}</p>
    <p class="redtext">{{ company_info.website }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. This one works as I wanted. But I also want to know if there is any way to run this condition inside HTML file?

Comment: well, you can use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) and sending all objects to the template to achieve this but it is better to do processing inside the views rather than templates.